# Fixing symbol cannot be found java on pl

Tags: java, oracle

```
.\Bulby\Gui.java:118: error: cannot find symbol
    pl.getActionSender().sendMessage(pl, "<col=336600>[Server Message] " + text);
    ^
    symbol:   method getActionSender()
    location: variable pl of type Player
    Note: .\Bulby\players\objectLoader.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    Note: .\Bulby\clanchat\Room.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
    Press any key to continue . . .














    /*
```

* Class Gui
 *
 * Version 1.0
 *
 * Thursday october 31 2013
 *
 * Created by Dragnnight
 */

```
package Bulby;
import Bulby.Server;
import Bulby.Engine;
import Bulby.players.Player;
import Bulby.util.Misc;
import Bulby.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame {

static private JTextField textkick;
private JLabel textt;
private JButton button1;
private JButton button2;
private JButton button3;
private JButton button4;
private JPanel panel;

public Gui() {
super("Your servers name goes here thank xx pkpure xx - Control Panel"); // The title bar
setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // This is the layout of the Gui
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

/**textt = new JLabel("Enter a name to kick.");                
textkick = new JTextField("Enter a username to kick");
textkick.setToolTipText("Type in the username to kick here.");
**/

button1 = new JButton("Kick"); //button on the gui
button1.setToolTipText("Kick a player."); //Hover text
            button1.setActionCommand("kick");

            button2 = new JButton("Get players count"); //button on the gui
            button2.setToolTipText("Get players count."); //Hover text
            button2.setActionCommand("gplayers");

            button3 = new JButton("Get players names"); //button on the gui
            button3.setToolTipText("Get players names."); //Hover text
            button3.setActionCommand("gnplayers");

            button4 = new JButton("Masstext"); //button on the gui
            button4.setToolTipText("Send a masstext."); //Hover text
            button4.setActionCommand("masstext");

            add(panel);

            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            /**
            c.gridx = 0; //Position of textt
            c.gridy = 0; // All of these are the X, Y position of the selected item
            panel.add(textt); //For example, here the selected item is "textt"
            c.gridx = 50;
            c.gridy = 5;
            panel.add(textkick);        
            c.gridx = 100;
            c.gridy = 10;
            **/ 
            panel.add(button1);
            panel.add(button2);
            panel.add(button3);
            panel.add(button4);

            button1.addActionListener(new Action()); //Adds an ActionListener to button1
            button2.addActionListener(new Action()); //Adds an ActionListener to button2
            button3.addActionListener(new Action()); //Adds an ActionListener to button3
            button4.addActionListener(new Action()); //Adds an ActionListener to button4
    }

    static class Action implements ActionListener {
       public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {



        if ("kick".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        String kickwho=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Username to kick");
            Player p2 = Server.engine.players[Engine.getIdFromName(kickwho)];
            System.out.println("[GUI] Kicked "+kickwho+" from the server."); //What happens when button1 is clicked
            }

            if ("gplayers".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Server.engine.getPlayerCount());
            }

            if("gnplayers".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            String names = "";
                            for (Player pl : Server.engine.players) {
                                            if (pl != null) {
                                                    names = names + pl.username + ", ";
                                            }
                            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, names);
            }

            if("masstext".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            String text=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Text:");
            int sent2 = 0;
                            for (Player pl : Server.engine.players) {
                                            if (pl != null) {

pl.getActionSender().sendMessage(pl, "<col=336600>[Server Message] " + text);

                                                    sent2++;

                                            }
                            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mass message sent to " + sent2 + " players.");
            }



                    }
            } 
    }
```

i just need some help identifying how to define Pl in the code because Above it i did define it but it didn't take and i'm not sure why or maybe i didn't define it right or something

Comment: would you mind showing the code of Player class?

Comment: Post the code for class Player and ancestors to get more help

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the `Player` class (`Bulby.players.Player` is your own class I believe) does not contain a method having signature `getActionSender()`.

Check if the method is present, and then whether it has a signature same as above (i.e., without arguments).

Comment: yes your right i did not catch that i had forgotten i had re-named ActionSender class file don't think i would have caught that nice catch and thank you